# Feature Request? Verify User Login Status from Server Side

Tags: facebook, session-state, facebook-login

I have a single page web app so I'm trying to avoid redirecting when users logs in.

I'd like to be able to pass the session data I get from FB.getLoginStatus() to my server, then have my server validate it with Facebook to be sure it was and is still valid. 
I'm using PHP.

Can this be done?  Or, is there another way to verify a user's session with Facebook from the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the facebook PHP SDK provided at [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).

After creating a Facebook object:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'FACEBOOK_SECRET',
        'fileUpload' => true, // file upload enabled in the server
```

You can use function getUser() to get the UID of the connected user, or 0
if the Facebook user is not connected.

```
$facebook->getUser();
```

Also you have available the funtction getLoginStatusUrl($params=array()) to get a login status URL to fetch the status from Facebook.

```
$facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
```

Hope this helped you. Follow this link to have an overview of the [PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/). Also you have some working examples in the GitHub repository.